# libgit2sharp what is correct sha to supply to GitHub API merge pull-request?

Tags: git, git-merge, github-api, sha, libgit2sharp

GitHub API requires merge pull-request to be submitted as

```
PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number/merge
```

with request body json

```
{
  "commit_message": "blah",
  "sha": "{SHA that pull request head must match to allow merge}",
}
```

Following a commit, push, create PR, what libgit2sharp property supplies the correct sha ?

For the current branch, it appears `Branch.Tip.Sha` is the correct value, but I'm receiving response error :

> {   "message": "Head branch was modified. Review and try the merge
>   again.",   "documentation_url":
>   "https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#merge-a-pull-request-merge-button"
>   }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two different commits and shas come into play when it comes to Pull Request.

- The tip of your branch (the very last commit you've pushed on your branch)

  - **Syntax:** `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/refs/:ref` (where `:ref` should be of the `pull/{number}/head` format)
  - **Example:** https://api.github.com/repos/libgit2/libgit2sharp/git/refs/pull/1123/head
- The virtual merge commit that GitHub dynamically creates behind the scene to determine mergeability and allow CI servers to run your build/tests as if your branch was already merged (and thus, detect in advance any potential issue)

  - **Syntax:** `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/refs/:ref` (where `:ref` should be of the `pull/{number}/merge` format)
  - **Example:** https://api.github.com/repos/libgit2/libgit2sharp/git/refs/pull/1123/merge

When leveraging the GitHub API to merge an opened Pull Request, the optional sha property from the json payload is expected to match the sha of the branch tip **as currently known by GitHub**.

Provided your local repository is in sync with what GitHub knows about your repository, this should definitely be matching what `repo.Branches["your_topic_branch"].Tip.Sha` returns.

**Note:** In order to ensure that the GitHub known head of the PR matches your local branch tip, using LibGit2Sharp, you can retrieve GitHub PR merge/head pointed at commits, by directly fetching a special reference namespace. The following code demonstrates this

```
var remoteName = "origin"; // or whatever your remote is named
var remote = repo.Network.Remotes[remoteName];
var prNumber = "1123"; // or whatever your pr number is

// Build the refspec
string refSpec = string.Format("+refs/pull/{1}/*:refs/remotes/{0}/pull/{1}/*", 
                        remoteName, prNumber);

// Perform the actual fetch
repo.Network.Fetch(remote, new[] { refSpec });

Console.WriteLine(repo.Branches[string.Format("pull/{0}/merge", prNumber)].Tip.Sha);
```

Comment: github support is telling me that the merge-pull-request api sha ( which is an optional param ) should be set to the sha of the most recent commit on the pull-request source branch as it exists on github

Comment: @BaltoStar I've updated the answer with some more troubleshooting tips.

Comment: my branch has no commits added manually, and my app rejects subsequent requests if an ongoing request is in progress -- enforcing only a single git client in progress at any given time -- so when my app programmatically attempts commit/push/create pull-request , it's local `Branch.Tip.Sha` should always match the latest sha on GitHub's virtual  merge pull-request branch , correct ?

Comment: Sounds correct. When you fetch, what do you get? "everything up to date"?

Comment: typically the response is "everything up to date" but occasionally I get 409 - this is totally baffling as I can find no causal relationship ( so far )

Comment: here's what's really strange : I removed the optional sha from the request json payload -- so I'm not asking GitHub to verify the merge is for a specific sha -- and now I occasionally get 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: Something's very weird if you local branch and upstream branch are in sync. Maybe should you report this to github support (linking to this SO question).